# Most common way to work with argparse parsed values

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

In using `argparse` this is the first time I've come across a 'Namespace' object. What is the most common way to work with these objects? For example, if I have this initialization code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dedupe library.', allow_abbrev=True)
parser.add_argument( '-a', '--all', nargs='+', type=int, help='(Optional) Enter one or more IDs.')
parser.add_argument( '-r', '--reverse', nargs='+', help='(Optional) Enter one or more IDs.')
```

It seems like the library adds a property on every `--long` option (if it exists, otherwise the short `-s` option), so something like the following works:

```
# test.py
p = parser.parse_args()
print (p.all, p.reverse)
# -------------------------------------
$ python test.py -a 2 3 -r asdf
# [2, 3] ['asdf']
```

Is this the most common way to work with the `argparse` output, or how is this usually done?

Comment: Yes, you access the argument values as attributes of the object returned by `parse_args()`. That's how it works. I'm not sure what you're after from this question that isn't covered by the documentation.

Comment: `p` produced by a `parse_args` is an `argparse.Namespace` object, a relatively simple object class.  I recommend doing a `print(p)` during debugging so you see the attribute names along with values.  Usually we access the values by attribute.  `vars(p)` makes a dictionary if you prefer that syntax.  `argparse` actually uses `getattr` and `setattr` functions, to give maximum flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every argument performs some kind of action, specified by the `action` argument to `add_argument`. The default is a `store` action.

Each `store` action saves one (or more) values to an attribute in the resulting namespace. You can specify which attribute with the `dest` argument to `add_argument`, but more commonly the name is inferred from the first long option name (or the first short name, if there are no long names).

Note that you can have multiple options that affect the same attribute. A common use is to have multiple `store_const` actions that save a different hard-coded value to a single attribute.

```
p.add_argument("--high", action='store_const', dest='level', const='high')
p.add_argument("--med", action='store_const', dest='level', const='medium')
p.add_argument("--low", action='store_const', dest='level', const='low')
```

You could consider this as providing a series of aliases for an option that takes an explicit argument to specify a level:

```
p.add_argument("--level", choices=['high', 'medium', low'])
```

where `--high` has the same effect as `--level high`.

```
>>> p.parse_args(["--level", "high"]).level
'high'
>>> p.parse_args(["--high"]).level
'high'
```